# How do I display this firebase branch's data to app?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

[Firebase Realtime Database tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stOOD.png)

I am new to Firebase and Java. All I need to do is display the single line Key1(image linked above) to my app.
This is the java I used:

```
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("ReNu");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String values = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    Temp.setText(values);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

The data from that specific line is not getting displayed and which means I am probably not getting the data correctly I assume.
I am not sure how to fix it- any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to display the value of the `key1` field that exists within your `ReNu` node, then please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference renuRef = db.child("ReNu");
renu.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            String key1 = snapshot.child("key1").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", key1);
            Temp.setText(key1);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
Temp=23.0*C Humidty=56.0%
```

Along with setting the same value to the `Text` TextView. Please also note that there is no need for an iteration, since there is only one child under `ReNu` node.

Comment: Hey Meow02. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Literal life savior omg thank you so much. I was building a passion project that tracks moisture etc from compost using a sensor, which had been bugging me for so.long.

Comment: You're very welcome. And good to hear that it worked :)